# Reactjs: List Returns an "..should have a unique 'key' prop" error if conditionally rendered

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a dynamic table.

React returns errors if it renders conditionally, but errors don't show without renders conditionally.

error: **Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.**

How to solve this problem?

```
const Table = () => {

  const columns = [
    { id: 1, title: "Name", accessor: "name" },
    { id: 2, title: "Server", accessor: "server", filter: true },
    { id: 3, title: "Profile", accessor: "profile", filter: true, sort: true },
    { id: 4, title: "MAC Address", accessor: "mac-address" },
    { id: 5, title: "Uptime", accessor: "uptime" },
    { id: 6, title: "Bytes in", accessor: "bytes-in" },
    { id: 7, title: "Bytes out", accessor: "bytes-out" },
    { id: 8, title: "Comment", accessor: "comment", filter: true, sort: true },
  ];
 
  return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {columns.map((col) => (
              // not throw error
              // <th
              //   className={getClassNamesFor(col.accessor)}
              //   name={col.accessor}
              //   onClick={handleSort}
              //   key={col.id}
              // >
              //   {col.title}
              // </th>

              <>
                {/* throw error */}
                {col.sort ? (
                  <th
                    className={getClassNamesFor(col.accessor)}
                    name={col.accessor}
                    onClick={handleSort}
                    key={col.id}
                  >
                    {col.title}
                  </th>
                ) : (
                  <th name={col.accessor} key={col.id}>
                    {col.title}
                  </th>
                )}
              </>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         // ...
        </tbody>
      </table>
  );
};
```

Comment: you are wrapping the children inside a fragment. the first child of the list should have the key (the the fragment in the throwing code)

Comment: @quirimmo can you provide sample code?

Comment: Remove the empty `<> </>` which are a shortcut for `Fragment`, because I think react want a key for the element that is mapped not any nested element like the conditional element you have.

Comment: use as wrapper <Fragment key={col.id} and remove the keys from the th, should work fine then

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having an issue like me, the code got around the problem.

```
{/* ..... */}
<thead>
  <tr>
    {columns.map((col) => (
      <Fragment key={col.id}>
        {col.sort ? (
          <th
            className={getClassNamesFor(col.accessor)}
            name={col.accessor}
            onClick={handleSort}
          >
            {col.title}
          </th>
        ) : (
          <th name={col.accessor}>{col.title}</th>
        )}
      </Fragment>
    ))}
  </tr>
</thead>
{/* ..... */}
```